# Sharepoint View Grouping - performance

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

If you add grouping to a list view does it inheretly improve performance when you navigate to the view in the sharepoint page? i.e. if you use grouping, does sharepoint retrieve data when you click the [+] icon (using an Ajax call)? or is the data already retrieved beforehand?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when u use grouping by default all your group document are not loaded first time. when u expand group it load all document.

After that using JavaScript it change the property from display none to display block and display block to display none and so on.

so according to performance it load all document first time but it's quick.

This is same for list also

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that using groupings loads all data at once. So if you have a list with 1000 items and you display a grouped view, you may experience very slow loading.

Comment: I have checked the HTML and it is does not contain the data. But perhaps internally, Sharepoint is loading all the information but is not sending it to the client ... who knows

Comment: It depends on whether you have the default set to expand or collapse the groups.  If they default to expanded then obviously it needs to contain the data.